# Method not called during ImageView onClick

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I am trying to develop the functionality, where the user can click on the image to select an image to upload on the same view being clicked. I define the ImageView as follows

```
    <ImageView
     style = "@style/DefaultButton"
     android:id="@+id/choose_img"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
     android:clickable="True"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     android:onClick="chooseImg"
     android:contentDescription="@string/description_logo"
     android:src="@drawable/user2" />
```

the method chooseImg is as follows

```
    public void chooseImg(View view){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Choose Image from Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent chimg = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        chimg.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(chimg,CHOOSE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

The method is not being called. please help me out to know the reason. Thanks :).

Comment: Is it just me, or is your method in the onClick called "captureImg" and the other one called "chooseImg"?

Comment: you can also do setOnClickListener (this) and have your activity implement onClick.

Comment: Please be sure to mark the answer as solved if casper was correct.

Comment: I am sry. tht was a typo. There is another method captureImg.While copy pasting, I had to add that line, cuz I resorted a different method to solve my issue. But I want to know Why this method Ain't working.

Comment: After I click on the image, the application gets stuck for a while and then goes for a force close. It doesn't even execute the Toast. I dont understand why. I used the onClickListener and had activity implemet onClick. It worked. But why isn't this method working?

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I have been very busy lately.  Could you update your question to indicate the last line of code that executes before the force close, as well as any log output that might be relevant?  Information like this is essential to solve any sort of runtime-error problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method that gets called by `android:onClick` must match the method that you want to be executed... But your method on onClick is `captureImg` and your method name in activity is `chooseImg`.  Change these to the same method name and it should solve your problem.  Also see my comment.

Comment: Can you please help me with an answer? I have edited my question. Is there anything missing in my question? please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Casper is correct.  I would add that you can have Activity itself implement View.OnClickListener interface

onClick(View v)
{
    if (v.getId() == (Id for ImageView)) 
     {
            captureImg();
     }

}

Or as an anonymous innner class.

Comment: Yes. I used that to solve my issue. But my question is why this method ain't working for me. Please help me here. Please see my edit. apologies for the wrong code.